# NSTableView problems - displaying custom TableView from with a SplitView panel

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nsview

I am developing my first app for OSX. Sorry for asking stupid questions. I have spent a few hours trying to figure this out on my own, with no luck so far.

I want to make an iTunes-like interface. I used NSSplitView, placed NSView for navigation and NSTableView above that. [I am aware that there better alternatives to NSSplitView, yet my goal is to both - develop an app and also to learn Cocoa/OSX in the process.]
Atop NSView panel designated for navigation, I am trying to place NSTableView. However, my table is not being displayed. I therefore have questions...

I understand that for cells to be populated, controller must implement NSTableViewDataSource. I tried that, but was so far unsuccessful - to the point that I don't see the table. Please advise:

1. Can I have a working NSTableView-derived custom class also implementing NSTableViewDataSource? If this cannot work, please advise why or point me to an explanation.
2. Am I correct in thinking that all elements can be manipulated programmatically, in the sense that I use IBOutlet in headers to point to the right object, yet do nothing with InterfaceBuilder - have everything controlled from within my Objective-C code? Do I have to use IB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes that will work but it's an unusual approach. Generally the tableview delegate/datasource is something enclosing the tableview.  You'd normally only subclass `NSTableView` if you require some additional functionality not provided by default (for me that has been custom behaviour to input).
2. Yes you can do it all programmatically, however you will find it much easier to use IB.  The IB-loaded views are created programmatically under the hood, using the information contained in the nib file.  You will find it long-winded and tedious pretty quickly.

WRT to your issue with not seeing the table, you will need to add logging/breakpoints on the few key delegate/datasource methods to ensure they are being called (start with the daddy of them all `numberOfRowsInTableView:`).  If they are not then you aren't setting the delegate/datasource correctly in the tableview.

Comment: Thank you. I did like you suggested - subclassed NSTableView and had the derived class implement the DataSource methods.

As far as IB being easier to use, I am sure you are right in general. I just don't see why I would need it, in my case. Instead of hiding and showing/adding Views, I can simply display them [the detail part] as needed. Perhaps, I am missing the point.
Thank you for the advice, though.

Do you know what could cause my NSTableView subclass not displaying? Would it help if I posted code? There is not much there - only things controlling the look.

Comment: @MosheShmukler Yeah more detail will always help (up to a point).

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate your help.
I have a panel - NSView. It is being displayed fine.

header:

Comment: Stackoverflow only allows posting once in 90 minutes. I am going to post as soon as the timeout expires. Much obliged for your assistance.

Comment: I posted code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913379/nstableview-is-not-being-displayed and additional details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969981/ongoing-nstableview-problems
Been stuck on this for a few days, now.