# Ongoing NSTableView problems

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am writing my first Cocoa/OSX app. I have been having problems with an NSTableView derived class. The problems is that there is no table in the containing NSView - the table is not visible.
I previously pasted my code at [NSTableView is not being displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25913379/nstableview-is-not-being-displayed)

If you know NSTableView well and it could assist, it would greatly help. I have spent a couple of days on this, with no luck.

Additional details:

1. NSLog shows that NSTableView subclass init() is called once. This is probably good. The method numberOfRowsInTableView() is called multiple times. I don't know whether this good or bad. The method tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row: is never invoked. The method drawRect() of NSView is called after initialization of TableView. Yet, commenting out [super drawRect:dirtyRect]; line changes nothing.
2. Please note that I use the same NSTableView subclass as [also] a NSTableViewDataSource. I understand that this is not the common "pattern," yet I don't see why this cannot work. If there is a logical explanation, please advise my approach is not workable.
3. I do not use and do not want to use InterfaceBuilder.

Thank you for taking time to read my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to come up with the solution. See the referred page for more information, if interested. Thanks.

BTW, the best NSTableView tutorial which I have seen - one that allowed me do what I needed is at: http://www.knowstack.com/nstableview_fromcode/